# Appending to list for shopping App

Tags: jquery, html

This is my first post here. I'm creating a shopping list app and having some difficulty with adding new items to my list. My attempt was to take the value of the input and append it to my list of items. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Shopping App</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <body background="images/image6.jpg">
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <H1>Shopping List</H1>
      </header>
      <p>
        Add Item: <input type= "text" name="sumbitText">
        <button class="addItem">Add Item</button>
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
      </p>
      <ul id="shoppingList">
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Apples</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Bananas</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Grapes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var addItem = $('.addItem');
    var removeItem = $('.remove');

    addItem.click = $(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=submitText]').val();
        $('#shoppingList').append('<li><input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have two body tags `<body>`,  `<body background="images/image6.jpg">`?

Comment: I did a search for inserting background images and came across this example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Comment: I know that seems very novice. I'm still learning. Do you have a better suggestion? I'm open to all feedback. Thank you!

Comment: As it's shown in that example, you can have only one body tag `<body background="images/image6.jpg">`.

Comment: I just noticed that too. Good catch! I will make the change. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are new to jQuery, you also have to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your `<head>` tags to make you jQuery work.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d41myzsm/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
         <H1>Shopping List</H1>
    </header>

    Add Item: <input id="text" type= "text" name="sumbitText">
    <button id="addItem">Add Item</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

    <ul id="shoppingList">
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Apples</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Bananas</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Grapes</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var addItem = $('#addItem');
    var removeItem = $('#remove');
    addItem.click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input#text').val();
        $('#shoppingList').append('<li><input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });
    removeItem.click(function () {
        var toRemove = $('input#text').val();
        $('li:contains('+toRemove+')').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var addItem = $('.addItem');
    var removeItem = $('.remove');

  addItem.click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('#sumbitText').val();
      $('#shoppingList').append('<li><input type="checkbox"/>' + toAdd + '</li>'); 
  });
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping App</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
    <body background="images/image6.jpg">
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <H1>Shopping List</H1>
            </header>
            <p>
                Add Item: <input type= "text" name="sumbitText" id="sumbitText">
                <button class="addItem">Add Item</button>
                <button class="remove">Remove</button>
            </p>
            <ul id="shoppingList">
              <li><input type="checkbox"/>Apples</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox"/>Bananas</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"/>Grapes</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

"addItem.click =" should be "addItem.click()"

The other change is that I added an id to the input as it is easier.

You can see it all working here : codepen.io/anon/pen/EIcKv

Comment: You don't have any events that removes the items.

Comment: Just got the add item to work! Remove item ..that's my next step. Thanks again for your help!!